# multiplying every nth row of a matrix by a number using sapply and for loop

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I have a 100 * 100 matrix and I a willing to multiply every tenth row by 10. 
I know that it would be easily doable by writing sth like:

```
tenthrows<-seq(from=10,to=100,by=10)  
m[tenthrows,]<-m[tenthrows,]*10
```

However I've asked to do this by using "for loop" and "sapply/lapply" functions.
I could do this by using only for loop like:

```
for (i in seq(from = 10 , to = 100, by = 10)) {m[i,]<-m[i,]*10 }
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate sapply/lapply also for doing so, any idea?
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning but I am using R.

Comment: `m * c(rep(1,9),10)`

Comment: thanks, i've tried this but it multiplies every tenth element not row.

Comment: actually, Farhad, @baptiste's answer *should* work (see below)

Comment: why is this "too broad"?  I can appreciate downvoting, or not answering, but this close reason doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a matrix:

```
m0 <- m <- matrix(1:1e4,100,100)
```

One way to do it:

```
tenthrows <- seq(1,100,by=10)
m[tenthrows,] <- m[tenthrows,]*10
```

Doing it with a `for` loop would be less efficient.  I can't think of a reason you would want to do it that way, unless (a) this is homework, (b) this is self-study, (c) there is some context you haven't told us about. If one of those is true, could you let us know?

Incorporating @baptiste's answer:

```
m2 <- m0 * c(10,rep(1,9))
all.equal(m,m2)  ## TRUE
```

This works because R stores matrices columnwise, so that multiplying every 10th element is equivalent to multiplying every 10th row.

Another possibility:

```
m3 <- sweep(m0,MARGIN=1,FUN="*",STAT=c(10,rep(1,9)))
all.equal(m,m3)  ## TRUE
```

Note that the difference between the original comment (`c(rep(1,9),10)`) depends on how you interpret "every 10th row"; the original comment multiplied rows 10,20,30,... whereas my answer is multiplying rows 1,11,21,31,...

```
library("rbenchmark")
benchmark(m[tenthrows,] <- m[tenthrows,]*10,
          m0*c(10,rep(1,9)),
          sweep(m0,MARGIN=1,FUN="*",STAT=c(10,rep(1,9))),
         replications=1000)
##                                    test replications elapsed relative 
## 2                 m0 * c(10, rep(1, 9))         1000   0.109    1.000 
## 1 m[tenthrows, ] <- m[tenthrows, ] * 10         1000   0.125    1.147
```

The `rep` approach is (slightly) faster.  (`sweep`, not shown, is even slower, although it's perhaps the most principled approach -- it's the one that is the closest to a direct translation of "multiply every 10th row by 10".  It's also worth keeping in mind that even the slowest approach took 0.25 seconds for 1000 replications of this task.)

Comment: Dear Ben, thank you so much for your help. I've gone through your code and it worked perfectly. this is actually part of my assignments and that's why i need to do this with use of for loop and sapply/lapply. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you explain what you've already tried, maybe someone will help (in general people don't like handing out answers to homework questions unless they help people *learn*, rather than just helping them succeed in courses)

Comment: Dear @Ben Bolker , this what I've think of so far>>>>> for (i in seq(from = 10 , to = 100, by = 10))
{
newmat[i,]<-newmat[i,]*10  
}     #this works fine but still I couldn't figure out how to use lapply/sapply functions.

Comment: p.s This is not like a "must do" assignment, I'm trying to learn R by myself, therefor i am trying to replicate the assignment from a course that friend of mine took.

Comment: can you edit your question to include this information?  It's actually sort of interesting/difficult/puzzling to think of a way to use lapply/sapply in this context ...

Comment: sure things @ben I did as you proposed.